# Can an collection that isn't fully immutable be declared `final` and treated as a constant?

Tags: java

In essence, I'm asking whether a collection can be treated as constant not because it is technically impossible to alter its elements, but because its elements are not intended to be altered, and will not be altered, in the course of execution? Say I declared an array like this:

```
package foo;

class Foo
{
    final static String[] SURNAMES = {"Beaufort", "Fitzroy",  
        "MacDonald"};

    // Other code...
}
```

I know that in this case, the array itself is `final` but its elements can still be altered. However, since I'm writing the rest of the package, I can ensure that they never will be. And if it was intended for use by others, it being uppercase and declared `final` would let users know that it should be treated as such, I would assume.

I'm relatively new to Java, and I was wondering whether doing this is unsafe or undesirable in some way, and if so, why that is, and what my alternatives are.

Comment: Define your use of _constant_. And what difference you think it would  make?

Comment: Can you use [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead?

Comment: The `final` keyword applied to a reference variable only keeps the reference variable from changing - not the array or object to which it points. You could guarantee immutability of the referenced list of members by using an [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-).

Comment: What does "treated as constant" mean, beyond the stipulation you've already made that you're in fact not going to change it?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I mean that neither the array nor its contents can be altered. Like I said, its contents could be in this case, but I still want to treat them as constant anyway.

Comment: That doesn't _mean_ anything to _treat them as a constant_. Fine, don't alter the contents. You have that option. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @PM-77-1 This is just an example. Assume that other collection types cannot/should not be used in this case.

Comment: After you win lottery and happily retire someone else might not have such dedication to maintain your effective immutability.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you all have answered my question. I suppose this is more about the precise definition of "constant", which by what you all are saying seems to be stricter than I thought it was, in the sense that it CANNOT be altered rather than will not or should not be altered. I appreciate it.

Comment: Just as a data point, [Google's Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.4-constant-names) stipulates that non-empty static final array names should not be written as constants because they're not constants, and "Merely intending to never mutate the object is not enough".

Comment: The JLS defines a _constant variable_ in §4.12.4 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4: "A _constant variable_ is a `final` variable of primitive type or type `String` that is initialized with a constant expression (§15.28)." Note that being a `static` or even member variable is not required.

Comment: It is sometimes permitted by a house style to name a `final` variable of an immutable type as a constant even if it's not a constant variable, but understand that the compiler does not treat such variables in the special way it does constant variables​.

Comment: There's no such thing as "partially immutable". So "not fully immutable" is a wordy but exact synonym for "mutable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You remark,

> I know that in this case, the array itself is `final` but its elements
>   can still be altered. However, since I'm writing the rest of the
>   package, I can ensure that they never will be. And if it was intended
>   for use by others, it being uppercase and declared `final` would let
>   users know that it should be treated as such, I would assume.

In this case, it being package-private is a far better signal to users not to muck with it.  In fact, they *cannot* see or touch it without resorting to reflection or JNI, or creating their own class in your package (the last of which you can prevent by sealing the package).  Do not rely on naming conventions for enforcing behavior.

But none of that prevents your own code from modifying the array elements, perhaps by accident.  If the correctness of your code depends on them not changing, then you should not leave the possibility open, *especially* with a `static` field.  You can't do that with an array, but you can with a *bona fide* `Collection`, such as a `List`.  Thus, consider this, instead:

```
class Foo {
    final static List<String> SURNAMES = Collections.unmodifiableList(
            Arrays.asList("Beaufort", "Fitzroy", "MacDonald") );

    // ...
}
```

A `List` -- especially one built in that way -- has properties similar to an array, and unlike an array, it can reject modification attempts, as that one will do.

Comment: ...or use an inherently immutable list implementation, like Guava's `ImmutableList`. Not a reason in and of itself to start using Guava, but certainly worth considering if you're already using it.